# Curl script to angularjs post call

Tags: angularjs, http, curl

```
curl -u username:password http://example.com -F file=@./file
```

How to add "username:password" in post call?

Comment: Could you manage to implement authentification with Angular ? Does my answer work in your case ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can find here a tutorial about how to to it : [HTTP Basic Authentication in AngularJS](http://olefriis.blogspot.ch/2014/01/http-basic-authentication-in-angularjs.html)

But basically it should be this way :

```
 var encodedUserNameAndPassword = encodeBase64(userName + ':' + password);
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encodedUserNameAndPassword;
```

You only need to do it once since it update default header from $http. After that all your calls will be authentificated.